# How to take user input in form of a matrix in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to make an app that take two matrix from the user and then we display it's multiplication.

I am new to kivymd, and can't figure it out how to take input from user and get all the value in the function on python file

Comment: Split the problem into smaller parts to make it easier to work on. For a start, do you know how to make a program to take any input from the user? Do you know how to pass that input to a function? If either of those things is a problem, focusing on that first will make it easier to take this next step.

Comment: I know the basics of python and functions but facing problem in  implimenting on kivy I know to take input using MDTextField in kivymd but don't know to take input in the form of matrix and pass that matrix in a function in my python file

Comment: The question is, what do you mean by "input in the form of a matrix". For instance, if you want your user to type in something like "[[1 2][3 4]]" then the answer is to do it the same way you already do but write a function to parse this input. On the other hand, if you want a special gui element for typing in matrix elements, the question is what do you want that to look like and then what is your problem with implementing that?

Comment: @inclement see this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643131/how-to-get-data-of-user-input-from-a-for-loop-to-python-file-in-kivymd). Here I have created a kivy page that contain 16 MDTextField **(arranged in the form of matrix)** the problem is, I can't access that user input in my python file. I have tried to create id's but that didn't work.